# How to Integrate Netsuite with 3rd party HRM software?

Tags: integration, netsuite, erp, suitescript2.0, suitetalk

I am new in development. My manager wants me to be ready with the Netsuite integration with a third party HRM software(named: MenaHRM) that is open for integration. Can anyone help me where to start? Any prerequisites? Please guide me.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-integrate-anything-netsuite-olivier-gagnon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple solution, check out Jitterbit iPaaS (integration) software.  It can connect pretty much anything to anything else (and handles NetSuite very well).

Outside of that if that software can send or receive via an API, webhooks, or even an automated export, you can build out scripts (RESTlets or Suitelets) in NetSuite.  The NetSuite scripts can either poll the other system for data (not the best, since you won't have "live" data), or receive updates each time the other system is touched.

I've built these custom integrations in the past (ZenDesk to NetSuite), using NetSuite, ZAT, and Python.  One thing to keep in mind, if you build it custom, is to watch out for circular references.  You don't want an update from system A triggering an update back to system A, because System B was updated by the integration. :)

Comment: thank you W3BGUY for giving me a start!